# Control is removed from old parent control but not if i use a List<Control>, why?

Tags: c#, list, web-controls

It's probably a very basic question about the behaviour of C# and `WebControl`. I got this working, but it would be nice if someone could clarify where the difference lays.

**Before**

I have a dictionary with a given key (Guid) and a `Panel`.

```
var tmpFormButtonPanel = new Panel();
 _formButtonPanelDict.TryGetValue(new Guid(_hiddenField.Value), out tmpFormButtonPanel);
```

This panel contains a `WebControl`. Now I'd like to assign this button to another panel.

```
if (tmpFormButtonPanel != null)
{
       var tmpControls = new List<Button>();
       foreach (Button tmpButton in tmpFormButtonPanel.Controls)
       {
            tmpControls.Add(tmpButton);
       }
       tmpControls.Reverse();
       foreach (var tmpButton in tmpControls)
       {
           tmpButton.AddCssClass("xy");
           _buttonPanel.Controls.Add(tmpButton);
       }
}
```

The moment I add the button to the `_buttonPanel`, it deletes the button out of `tmpFormButtonPanel`. From what I've heard or read, a WebControl can only be assigned to one panel. So this would explain why it doesn't work.

So I changed the code to this.

```
var tmpFormButtonList = new List<ButtonBaseUc>();
 if (!_formButtonDict.TryGetValue(new Guid(_hiddenField.Value), out tmpFormButtonList))
{
       tmpFormButtonList = new List<ButtonBaseUc>();
       _formButtonDict.Add(new Guid(_hiddenField.Value), tmpFormButtonList);
}
foreach (var tmpButton in tmpFormButtonPanel.Controls)
{
       if (tmpButton is ButtonBaseUc)
       {
            tmpFormButtonList.Add((ButtonBaseUc)tmpButton);
       }
}
```

The last part does the same thing, but on the `tmpFormButtonList`.

```
if (tmpFormButtonList!= null)
{
    var tmpControls = new List<Button>();
    foreach (Button tmpButton in tmpFormButtonList)
    {
         tmpControls.Add(tmpButton);
    }
    tmpControls.Reverse();
    foreach (var tmpButton in tmpControls)
    {
          tmpButton.AddCssClass("xy");
          _buttonPanel.Controls.Add(tmpButton);
     }
  }
```

This is working. But why? I am only assigning the button to another list before adding it to the new panel. The references are still the same. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works in the second approach. Anyway, why do you need to move this button-webcontrol from panel1 to panel2 without removing it from the first panel? Is the reason that you still need it in the `tmpFormButtonList`-Panel of the dictionary? Then don't use a `Control` as container but a `List<ButtonBaseUc>` as `Value` for the dictionary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah snap, that's the difference. In the second approach I use a List<ButtonBasUc> instead of a panel! That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control can only belong to one parent control. Since you have assigned it to the `Panel` in the dictionary-value, it will be removed there if you move it to the `_buttonPanel`.

This isn't [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) but you can see it in the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Control.cs,2ed53dced1207154):

```
// ...
if (control._parent != null) {
   control._parent.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

You have fixed this by not using a `Panel` as "storage" but a `List<ButtonBaseUc>`. This list is not a control(so the control has no parent), hence it must not be removed if you assign it to another (parent-)control.